# kaminari - redirect to last page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

So I've got pagination with Kaminiari set up on my app, which is a forum. When someone replies to the thread, I want to direct them to the last page of the thread. It seems like it'd be easy enough to hard code the logic to get the last page based on what I'm using for record numbers, but is there a built in method to get the last page?

Comment: What version of Kaminari are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In my current version of kaminari (v0.12.4) the following works:

```
users = User.page(params[:page])
last_page = users.num_pages
```

`num_pages` is defined in https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/models/page_scope_methods.rb.
If you want to add a `last_page` method, I suggest the following:

```
module Kaminari
  module PageScopeMethods
    def last_page
      num_pages
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [this thread](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/150) has an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I gave that a shot, but it says num_pages isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to achieve this if not already present in Kaminari . This should be present since Kaminari also renders the page numbers for navigation.

Say, @records is list of db records where you performed @records.page(1) to show the get the current set of records,

The last page number is defined by `(@records.total_count / per_page.to_f).ceil` .

Answer (score 0):

For other people's sake, I'll share what worked for me.

#### Associations

1. Conversation has_many Messages
2. Message belongs_to Conversation

In Conversation show page, I want to paginate every 10 messages

```
messages = conversation.messages.page(params[:page]).per(10)
last_page = messages.total_pages
```

Then I want to create a link to this show page which will show me the last page. I just made a helper method

```
def create_link_to_last_page(conversation)
    content_tag :div do
      link_to("Show", url_for(controller: 'conversations', action: 'show', id: conversation.id, page: last_page))
    end
end
```